# Definition of induced representation for Lie algebras

Tags: modules, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Given a Lie algebra g, a Lie module of g is a couple $(V,f)$, where V is a vector space and
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f: g \times V & \rightarrow V \\
(g,v) & \mapsto f(g,v)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
is a map that mantains the structure of Lie bracket of g.

If h is a Lie subalgebra of g, and W is a Lie module of h, the vector space
$$ U(g) \otimes_{U(h)} V$$
has a structure of Lie module on g, called the induced representation.
How is defined the map $f$ in this case?

Answer (score 3):

It is defined as$$f(X,u\otimes v)=(Xu)\otimes v.$$